# Rules for appointing (requesting) a priest (ritwik)

Tags: priests

Medatithi's [Manu Bhashya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199613.html), while explaining who Ritwik is, says:

> ‘Being appointed’—being requested; i.e., whose appointment has been made in **accordance with the rules laid down in the scriptures.**

Question is, what are these rules for appointment of priests for sacrifices/rituals?

*Note: question is more about Devatas related and not Pitrus (where certification of brahmanas is required)*